# jQuery get previous elements until contain an element with id containing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use jQuery to select elements using .prevUntil until and element which contains an input with an id that includes a particular string. I think this should be possible but I can't seem to get it working.

Example html:

```
<ul>
    <li><input /></li>
    <li><input id="stop" /></li>
    <li><input /></li>
    <li><input /></li>
    <li><input /></li>
    <li><input id="start" /></li>
    <li><input /></li>
</ul>
```

Example javascript:

```
list = $('#start').parent().prevUntil('li:contains("input[id*=\'stop\']")';
list.css('background-color', 'red');
```

There is a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/60uv01ps/).

If example was working correctly, every element from the li containing #start to li containing #stop would be red.

Comment: Any specific reason you went with the *second* answer posted? Did I miss something specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector instead of [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector as the [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) select elements which contain the specified text not attribute

```
$('#start').parent().prevUntil('li:has([id*="stop"])')
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/udmrLppc/)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, what is the reason the way I wrote it didn't work?

Comment: But can I specify that it must be an input with id containing?

Comment: @LukeCaldwell, yes `.prevUntil('li:has(input[id*="stop"])') `

Comment: Why make the selector inside `has` so complicated? [TrueBlueAussie's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31586631/157247) is much simpler and more direct.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: To answer your question (now I have the full info)... Because the OP did not bother to mention that the identifiers are generated strings that need *partial matching* (i.e. they all start with stop). Of course that means the `start` marker is equally wrong, so this answer is not complete either. I have deleted my answer and will take a break from stupidity for a few days. Ciao for niao :)

Comment: @LukeCaldwell: That information really ought to have been in the question.

Comment: It is. The question title says "get previous elements until contain an element with id _containing_". And first sentence says "with an id which _includes a particular string_"? It doesn't say that the start marker needs to have this condition.